# jQuery autocomplete works only after the corresponding <input> tag is used atleast once after starting the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, autocomplete

I recently started using jQuery in my code and used the latest jQuery autocomplete plugin in my project.

Basically, there's a log in screen and when you start typing the username, the autocomplete plugin does its magic and fetches the available usernames corresponding to the given input using MySql database.

It works perfectly fine except for the first time when I open the browser. The autocomplete fails to work ( Even observed it using firebug, the request was failing ) and once I logged in - logged out - tried to log in again, it started working again.

I tried this in Chrome - Mozilla and IE 9 and the results were the same. If I restart my browser again, the same thing repeats. For the first time the request fails and then works perfectly for the corresponding requests.

P.S: I am using CodeIgniter for backend coding of the project.

Jquery:

`<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#username").autocomplete({
                            source:'controller_name/get_usernames',
                            minLength:1
                        });
                    });
            <script>`

Comment: So, you are giving the public access to all usernames in your DB?

Comment: In another note, it sounds like it is not called when form loads, but instead after an event.   Do you have code for us?  You might want to encapsulate in `$(function(){/*...*/});`

Comment: Why would you be giving the usernames at a log in screen?

Comment: How does the request fail?

Comment: Autocomplete for user names hahaha a hacker's paradise.

Comment: I will post the code later but yeah, this is a "requirement" so I "have" to do it not that I "want" to do it, don't worry about hackers - it's mine to wory and would be great if people could refrain themselves from posting useless comments.

Comment: What was the error message in firebug for the request?

Comment: It says "GET http://localhost/project/controller_name/get_usernames?term=ad
 
404 Not Found" the first time ( ad are the letters that I typed ) inside #username. In the second occurrence ( i.e; once I've logged in - logged out and typed again ), I get 200 OK instead of Error 404.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

I changed the source to

`source:'<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controller_name/get_usernames',`

and now it works perfectly, thank you all for your time :D